# How to send PDF in NestJS and GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to expose a GraphQL `query`, using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com), that downloads a PDF but I'm getting this error:

> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

This is my resolver code:

```
@Query()
async generatePdf(
    @Args('id') id: string,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const buffer : Buffer = await this.service.generatedPdf(id);
    const stream = new Readable();  
    stream.push(buffer);
    stream.push(null);
    res.req.res.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      'Content-Length': buffer.length,
    });
    stream.pipe(res.req.res);
  }
```

I can't find any example of how to do it, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [res.download()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download).